# How do I edit the HTML of FormBuilder elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm using the [Skeleton CSS boilerplate](http://getskeleton.com/) which requires `input` checkboxes to be children the `label` tag for correct styling:

```
<label class="example-send-yourself-copy">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="label-body">Send a copy to yourself</span>
</label>
```

However, the Rails `collection_check_boxes` FormBuilder method only outputs `input` directly before `label`.

```
<input id="movie_genre_ids_1" name="movie[genre_ids][]" type="checkbox">
<label for="movie_genre_ids_1">Action</label>
```

How can I manipulate the template for the FormBuilder object?

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered what `&block` means in the api docs...
Basically, I need to call each method in a block:

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name do |check|%>
    <%= check.check_box %>
    <%= check.label %>
<% end %>
```